# Using a single JTextArea with multiple UndoManagers

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, undo, redo

I have a `JTextArea` and a `JComboBox` to allow me to cycle through various open files - the contents of the `JTextArea` change as I select a different file. I am trying to maintain a different Undo buffer per file and have defined a separate `UndoManager` per file.

I have created a simpler SSCCE to demonstrate my problem using two buffers, which I call "One" and "Two" - with a simple button to switch between them. Once an `UndoableEdit` happens, it checks the active buffer and performs an `addEdit()` on the respective `UndoManager`. When the "Undo" button is pressed, then it checks `canUndo()` and performs an `undo()` on the respective `UndoManager`. I have a flag called `ignoreEdit`, which is used when switching between buffers to ignore those edits from being recorded.

If I never switch between the buffers, then I don't have a problem, Undo works as expected. It is only when I switch between the buffers and appear to "break" the Document, does it fail. The following steps can be used to recreate the problem:

In buffer "One", type:

```
THIS
IS ONE
EXAMPLE
```

Switch to buffer "Two", type:

```
THIS
IS ANOTHER
EXAMPLE
```

Switch to buffer "One" and press the "Undo" button multiple times. After a few Undo operations, the buffer looks like this (with no way for the cursor to select the first two lines). However, the contents of `textArea.getText()` are correct as per the `System.out.println()` - so, it looks like a rendering issue?

```
THIS

THISIS ONE
```

This can't be the first time that someone has tried to implement independent Undo buffers per file? I am obviously doing something wrong with the Document model and inherently breaking it, but I looking for some advice on how best to fix this?

The code for the SSCCE is included below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.undo.*;

public class SSCCE extends JFrame implements ActionListener, UndoableEditListener {
  private final JLabel labTextArea;
  private final JTextArea textArea;
  private final JScrollPane scrollTextArea;
  private final Document docTextArea;
  private final JButton bOne, bTwo, bUndo;
  private final UndoManager uOne, uTwo;
  private String sOne, sTwo;
  private boolean ignoreEdit = false;

  public SSCCE(String[] args) {
    setTitle("SSCCE - Short, Self Contained, Correct Example");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300, 200);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    labTextArea = new JLabel("One");
    getContentPane().add(labTextArea, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    uOne = new UndoManager();
    uTwo = new UndoManager();
    sOne = new String();
    sTwo = new String();

    textArea = new JTextArea();
    docTextArea = textArea.getDocument();
    docTextArea.addUndoableEditListener(this);
    scrollTextArea = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    getContentPane().add(scrollTextArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel pButtons = new JPanel();
    bOne = new JButton("One");
    bOne.addActionListener(this);
    bOne.setFocusable(false);
    pButtons.add(bOne, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    bTwo = new JButton("Two");
    bTwo.addActionListener(this);
    bTwo.setFocusable(false);
    pButtons.add(bTwo, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    bUndo = new JButton("Undo");
    bUndo.addActionListener(this);
    bUndo.setFocusable(false);
    pButtons.add(bUndo, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    getContentPane().add(pButtons, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    setVisible(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource().equals(bOne)) {
      if (!labTextArea.getText().equals("One")) {
        sTwo = textArea.getText();
        ignoreEdit = true;
        textArea.setText(sOne);
        ignoreEdit = false;
        labTextArea.setText("One");
      }
    }
    else if (e.getSource().equals(bTwo)) {
      if (!labTextArea.getText().equals("Two")) {
        sOne = textArea.getText();
        ignoreEdit = true;
        textArea.setText(sTwo);
        ignoreEdit = false;
        labTextArea.setText("Two");
      }
    }
    else if (e.getSource().equals(bUndo)) {
      if (labTextArea.getText().equals("One")) {
        try {
          if (uOne.canUndo()) {
            System.out.println("Performing Undo for One");
            uOne.undo();
            System.out.println("Buffer One is now:\n" + textArea.getText() + "\n");
          }
          else {
            System.out.println("Nothing to Undo for One");
          }
        }
        catch (CannotUndoException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      else if (labTextArea.getText().equals("Two")) {
        try {
          if (uTwo.canUndo()) {
            System.out.println("Performing Undo for Two");
            uTwo.undo();
            System.out.println("Buffer Two is now:\n" + textArea.getText() + "\n");
          }
          else {
            System.out.println("Nothing to Undo for Two");
          }
        }
        catch (CannotUndoException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void undoableEditHappened(UndoableEditEvent e) {
    if (!ignoreEdit) {
      if (labTextArea.getText().equals("One")) {
        System.out.println("Adding Edit for One");
        uOne.addEdit(e.getEdit());
      }
      else if (labTextArea.getText().equals("Two")) {
        System.out.println("Adding Edit for Two");
        uTwo.addEdit(e.getEdit());
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        new SSCCE(args);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for SSCCE :-), search for AbstractUndoableEdit that override UndoManager

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but it seems to work okay for me. Have you considered using separate `UndoableEditListener`s which wrap the `UndoManager` and simply switching those instances??

Comment: you [can to start with](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12858747/714968) by @aterai

Comment: Why you don't use the one JTextArea per file? Simply layout these areas in a CardLayout - and user see each time only one JTextArea.

Comment: I have thought about this, but I can have a lot of potential buffers - they are part of a code snippet library where I might have 10, 20 or 30 of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously I had attempted to create a new instance of the `Document` class (each referencing the same Undo listener) and was going to use `JTextArea.setDocument()` instead of `JTextArea.setText()`. However, `Document` is an interface and can't be instantiated, but after reading the reference that mKorbel posted, I tried this using the `PlainDocument` class instead, which worked.

I have decided to maintain a `HashMap<String, Document>` to contain my `Document` classes and switch between them. When I switch the `Document`, I don't see the Undo/Redo issue - I suppose as I am no longer breaking the `Document`.

Updated SSCCE below which now uses `JTextArea.setDocument()` instead of `JTextArea.setText()`. This also has the advantage of not requiring the `ignoreEdit` boolean as `setDocument()` doesn't trigger an `UndoableEditEvent`, whereas `setText()` does. Each `Document` then references the local classes `UndoableEditListener`.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.undo.*;

public class SSCCE extends JFrame implements ActionListener, UndoableEditListener {
  private final JLabel labTextArea;
  private final JTextArea textArea;
  private final JScrollPane scrollTextArea;
  private final Document docTextArea;
  private final JButton bOne, bTwo, bUndo;
  private final UndoManager uOne, uTwo;
  private Document dOne, dTwo;

  public SSCCE(String[] args) {
    setTitle("SSCCE - Short, Self Contained, Correct Example");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300, 200);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    labTextArea = new JLabel("One");
    getContentPane().add(labTextArea, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    uOne = new UndoManager();
    uTwo = new UndoManager();
    dOne = new PlainDocument();
    dTwo = new PlainDocument();
    dOne.addUndoableEditListener(this);
    dTwo.addUndoableEditListener(this);

    textArea = new JTextArea();
    docTextArea = textArea.getDocument();
    docTextArea.addUndoableEditListener(this);
    textArea.setDocument(dOne);
    scrollTextArea = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    getContentPane().add(scrollTextArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel pButtons = new JPanel();
    bOne = new JButton("One");
    bOne.addActionListener(this);
    bOne.setFocusable(false);
    pButtons.add(bOne, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    bTwo = new JButton("Two");
    bTwo.addActionListener(this);
    bTwo.setFocusable(false);
    pButtons.add(bTwo, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    bUndo = new JButton("Undo");
    bUndo.addActionListener(this);
    bUndo.setFocusable(false);
    pButtons.add(bUndo, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    getContentPane().add(pButtons, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    setVisible(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource().equals(bOne)) {
      if (!labTextArea.getText().equals("One")) {
        textArea.setDocument(dOne);
        labTextArea.setText("One");
      }
    }
    else if (e.getSource().equals(bTwo)) {
      if (!labTextArea.getText().equals("Two")) {
        textArea.setDocument(dTwo);
        labTextArea.setText("Two");
      }
    }
    else if (e.getSource().equals(bUndo)) {
      if (labTextArea.getText().equals("One")) {
        try {
          if (uOne.canUndo()) {
            System.out.println("Performing Undo for One");
            uOne.undo();
            System.out.println("Buffer One is now:\n" + textArea.getText() + "\n");
          }
          else {
            System.out.println("Nothing to Undo for One");
          }
        }
        catch (CannotUndoException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      else if (labTextArea.getText().equals("Two")) {
        try {
          if (uTwo.canUndo()) {
            System.out.println("Performing Undo for Two");
            uTwo.undo();
            System.out.println("Buffer Two is now:\n" + textArea.getText() + "\n");
          }
          else {
            System.out.println("Nothing to Undo for Two");
          }
        }
        catch (CannotUndoException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void undoableEditHappened(UndoableEditEvent e) {
    if (labTextArea.getText().equals("One")) {
      System.out.println("Adding Edit for One");
      uOne.addEdit(e.getEdit());
    }
    else if (labTextArea.getText().equals("Two")) {
      System.out.println("Adding Edit for Two");
      uTwo.addEdit(e.getEdit());
    }
  }

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        new SSCCE(args);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why, but I when I ran your code in my office PC this morning I got the same issue which you got. At that time I did not have enough time to look into the code. So after I came back to my home I ran the code in my home PC, and its working fine !! I am not able to reproduce the issue. So may be this is a rendering issue.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I can produce it consistently on my work PC running Java 1.8, but I am about to try on my Mac running Java 1.6 to see if I get the same thing. I have also noticed occassionally, it also generates `javax.swing.text.StateInvariantError: Can't render line: 0` exception.

Comment: I see the same thing under Java 1.6 on a Mac as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer *per se*, but a demonstration of a different way of approaching the same problem.

What this does is wraps the `UndoableEditListener` in a self managed proxy, which has it's own `UndoManager` and `Document`.

Tested this with Java 7 and Java 8:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.UndoableEditEvent;
import javax.swing.event.UndoableEditListener;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;
import javax.swing.undo.UndoManager;

public class UndoExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new UndoExample();
    }

    private int index = 0;
    private Map<String, Undoer> mapUndoers;
    private JTextArea ta;
    private Undoer current;

    public UndoExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                mapUndoers = new HashMap<>(2);
                mapUndoers.put("One", new Undoer());
                mapUndoers.put("Two", new Undoer());

                ta = new JTextArea(4, 20);
                ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
                ta.setLineWrap(true);

                JButton btnOne = new JButton("One");
                JButton btnTwo = new JButton("Two");
                ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        install(e.getActionCommand());
                    }
                };
                btnOne.addActionListener(al);
                btnTwo.addActionListener(al);

                JButton undo = new JButton("Undo");
                undo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if (current != null) {
                            current.undo();
                        }
                    }
                });

                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                panel.add(btnOne);
                panel.add(btnTwo);
                panel.add(undo);

                install("One");

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(ta));
                frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void install(String name) {
        Undoer undoer = mapUndoers.get(name);
        if (undoer != null) {
            current = undoer;
            undoer.install(ta);
        }
    }

    public class Undoer implements UndoableEditListener {

        private UndoManager undoManager;
        private Document doc;

        public Undoer() {
            undoManager = new UndoManager();
            doc = createDocument();
            doc.addUndoableEditListener(this);
        }

        public void undo() {
            undoManager.undo();
        }

        public void undoOrRedo() {
            undoManager.undoOrRedo();
        }

        protected Document createDocument() {
            return new PlainDocument();
        }

        public void install(JTextComponent comp) {
            comp.setDocument(doc);
        }

        @Override
        public void undoableEditHappened(UndoableEditEvent e) {
            undoManager.addEdit(e.getEdit());
        }

    }

}
```